# Add labels to a bar chart of monthly totals

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, bar-chart, summary

I built a barplot in R where each bar represents the cummulative rainfall for a given month in a year. However, the bars themselves don't have  labels, and my boss is really emphasizing the fact that they should. Whenveer I try to add labels it alwyas adds way more than I need to. Any advice?

Here's the code I'm using right now:

[image: code and image of plot]

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Please do not post an image of code/data/errors [for these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Just include the code, console output, or data (e.g. `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might need to summarize the data first, your plot is combining al the values for the month, so when you label it it labels each terra::plot(rnaturalearth::ne_countries(returnclass = "sf")["geometry"])ortino o fthe bar.  If you use prism2018 <-prism2018 %>$ group_by(Month)%>%summarise(ppt=sum(ppt)) then you shoudl get one value to label per month.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you did not aggregate your data by month in `geom_text` as you did for your bars, i.e. you have to use a `stat_summary` with `geom="text"` for your labels. Otherwise you end up with multiple labels per month.

However, IMHO an easier approach would be to aggregate your dataframe outside of `ggplot()`.

Using some fake random example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)

set.seed(123)

prism2018 <- data.frame(
  Month = rep(
    seq.Date(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-01"), by = "month"),
    10
  ),
  `ppt (inches)` = runif(120),
  check.names = FALSE
)

prism2018 |>
  group_by(Month) |>
  summarise(`ppt (inches)` = sum(`ppt (inches)`, na.rm = TRUE)) |>
  ggplot(aes(Month, `ppt (inches)`)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = prettyNum(`ppt (inches)`, digits = 3)),
    vjust = 0, position = position_nudge(y = .05)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: How could I use my own data instead of random data if I aggregated outside of ggplot?

Comment: From the provided information I tried to mimic your data as close as possible. So in principle the code should work on the data you passed to `ggplot()`. If run into any issues then I would suggest to include a snippet of your real data. To that end have a look at the [link]((https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)) I already provided in my comment.